# How to filter sharepoint list with CAML query with more than one filters

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016

The following filter CAML query is working as expect. I would like to add filter for record that only created today. Are you able to point out what i have missed or done incorrectly. Thank you.

I have tried three different options below:

```
**Option 1:** 
$query.Query ="<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="EmpName"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">" + $searchValue + "</Value></Eq><Gt><FieldRef Name='Created' Type='DateTime'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Gt></And></Where>"

**Option 2:**
  $query.Query ="<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="EmpName"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">" + $searchValue + "</Value></Eq><Gt><FieldRef Name='Created' Type='DateTime'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Gt></And></Where>"



**Option 3:**
      $query.Query ="<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="EmpName"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">" + $searchValue + "</Value></Eq><Gt><FieldRef Name='Created' Type='DateTime'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-360'/></Value></Gt></And></Where>"
```

===========================================================================

**Full Code below:**

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://devsp01/"


$list1 = $web.Lists["DataCheck"]
$list2 = $web.Lists["Reports"]

foreach($item1 in $list1.Items)
{
    $searchValue = $item1["EmpName"]

    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"

    $query.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='EmpName' /><Value Type='Text'>" + $searchValue + "</Value></Contains></Where>"
    $items2 = $list2.GetItems($query)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in FieldRef.  `<FieldRef Name='Created' Type='DateTime'/>`. Remove **Type** from **FieldRef**.

Try with this

```
<FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
```

Replace Gt with Eq

```
<Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Created'  />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>

<Today />

      </Value>
    </Eq>
```

Full query

```
$query.Query ="<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="EmpName"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">" + $searchValue + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq></And></Where>"
```